# Parsing Html in VBA using a query get request

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I am using someone else's code because this is an old file other people are using, I want to update it to make it more efficient but I need a little help. Below is the vba operation. What I need is it to get the information but delete everything but a certain word which changes every time the operation is run. I could use regex and objRE.Pattern = "|" but the word changes depending on the status.

HTML:

```
<span  onmouseover="ShowText('Message','blahblah'); return true;" 
onmouseout="HideText('Message'); return true;" 
href="javascript:ShowText('Message')">---(PSA)---</span>
</font><a href='?srn=numbers12131131'target='_self'><font color='#6666FF' 
size='3'>numbers123232343</font></a><font  size='3'>----Installed----MUM 
Indication:In Scope-<font color='#00CC00'>PASS WITH WARNING</font>--- (20181018) 
</td><tr></table> </b><br>
<table class="OrderForm" width="1000"> '
```

I just want the Installed status in my excel sheet.

VBA code that needs work:

```
Sub GetComment()

Dim book As Workbook
Dim sheet As Worksheet
Dim row As Integer
Dim SRN As String
Dim whttp As Object


Set book = ThisWorkbook
Set sheet = book.Worksheets("CMT Data")
Set whttp = CreateObject("WinHTTP.WinHTTPrequest.5.1")


row = 2
SRN = sheet.Cells(row, 1)
Do While SRN <> ""
    Debug.Print SRN
    whttp.Open "GET", "www.websitedatgoeshere.com" & SRN, False
    whttp.SetRequestHeader "Cookie", "mycookiefromwebsite;"
    whttp.send
    Debug.Print whttp.responseText
    sheet.Cells(row, 2) = whttp.responseText
    row = row + 1
    SRN = sheet.Cells(row, 1)

Loop

Set whttp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: So what is the installed status from the above please i.e. the expected string to retain? And what is the value of SRN? Please give an example. Is the real URL a public facing URL? Otherwise, can you include the full responseText? If too long you can use a https://pastebin.com/.

Comment: `websitedatgoeshere.com" & SRN` what, as @QHarr has asked do these values look like.  If they are just ID's it wont work as you'll have `.com1234` rather than something like `.com/?id=1234`

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. i'm not sure what you mean by your first question. The information i want the string to retain is the status the word 'installed' or what ever variant is shown when the page is loaded.  The Value of the SRN is a numbered ID written into the cell in the sheet so something like 156789. the real URL is private. The full response text will change give the SRN but here is an example.

Comment: Is websitedatgoeshere.com" & SRN valid? And is it always "----targetWord----MUM"  Do you mind providing a pastebin of the full html ?

Comment: yes it works when fetching the data. i can not post more of the site information. maybe if guys can not help i need to rethink the code completely

Comment: Is it always between ---- and ---- , and is this the only occurence of ---- word ---- in the html?

Comment: yes its always between --- and ---, and the word will change but it normally is the only occurrence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is based on if, and only if, the word is always between "----" and "----", and that it is the first occurrence in the response. If not the first you can adjust the index 1 as required.

```
Debug.Print Split(Split(whttp.responseText, "----")(1), "----")(0)
sheet.Cells(row, 2) = Split(Split(whttp.responseText, "----")(1), "----")(0)
```

Comment: Thank you. it did not seem to work, i got a compile error: invalid or unqualified reference. this happened before when i tried splitting. im not sure why this happens. ive tried changing .responsetext but that does not seem to work.

Comment: Use whttp.responseText  if not within a With statement holding the http object.

Comment: Debug.Print whttp.responseText
        sheet.Cells(row, 2) = whttp.responseText
        row = row + 1
        SRN = sheet.Cells(row, 1)
        Debug.Print Split(Split(whttp.responseText, "----")(1), "----")(0)
        
        
    Loop

Comment: Remove the debug.print if using that way i.e. sheet.Cells(row, 2) = Split(Split(whttp.responseText, "----")(1), "----")(0)

Comment: that made sense Thank you very much.

Comment: its kind of working. it wont go into the correct row now though. when i change the row to row 1 an error appears.

Comment: You will need to debug with f8 and find out what is happening. What is the error message? And what does go into correct row mean please?

Comment: Pleasure. Glad it helped.